# Doing JSR-303 validation in logical order

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation

I have such field in my domain model class validation constraints:

```
@Column(nullable = false, name = "name")
    @NotEmpty(groups = {Envelope.Insert.class, Envelope.Update.class})
    @Size(min = 3, max = 32)
    private String name;
```

When this field is empty ("") or null, validator produces both "cannot be empty" and "size must be between..." error messages. I understand it, but when I show this validation error to the client, it seems quite odd (because when something is null / empty it cannot fulfill size requirement, it's not a logical).

Is there some way how to tell Spring to do validation in proper order? If is not `@NotEmpty` then do not check `@Size`, and when `@NotEmpty` is fulfilled check `@Size`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Hibernate official document:](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e968)

> By default, constraints are evaluated in no particular order and this
>   regardless of which groups they belong to. In some situations,
>   however, it is useful to control the order of the constraints
>   evaluation. In order to implement such an order one would define a new
>   interface and annotate it with @GroupSequence defining the order in
>   which the groups have to be validated.

At first, create two interface FirstOrder.class and SecondOrder.class and then define a group sequence inside OrderedChecks.java using `@GroupSequence` annotation.

```
public interface FirstOrder {
}

public interface SecondOrder {
}

@GroupSequence({FirstOrder.class, SecondOrder.class})
public interface OrderedChecks {
}
```

Finally, add groups in your bean constraints annotations.

```
@Column(nullable = false, name = "name")
@NotEmpty(groups = {FirstOrder.class, Envelope.Insert.class, Envelope.Update.class})
@Size(min = 3, max = 32, groups=SecondOrder.class)
private String name;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following example is taken from the [JSR-303 docs](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#validationapi-validatorapi-groups)

```
public class Address {
    @NotEmpty(groups = Minimal.class)
    @Size(max=50, groups=FirstStep.class)
    private String street1;

    @NotEmpty(groups=SecondStep.class)
    private String city;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {Minimal.class, SecondStep.class})
    private String zipCode;
    ...

    public interface FirstStep {}

    public interface SecondStep {}

    @GroupSequence({Firststep.class, SecondStep.class})
    public interface Total {}
}
```

and calling the validator like this

```
validator.validate(address, Minimal.class, Total.class);
```