# check if field already violates some rules before applying custom

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I have my custom validation annotation and it's validator. What I wan't to is to apply this custom validator only if field doesn't violate other resttictions. Assume following code

```
class MyClass {

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 10, max = 20)
  @MyCustomVlidatorAnnotation
  private String field;

}
```

I want to apply custom validator only if `field` is not null and has size in range [10, 20], otherwise skip my custom validator

Comment: You can try order your constraints, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42447596/12176589)

Comment: @user12176589 but how to check in the custom validator whether previous constraints were already violated?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `@javax.validation.GroupSequence`.

```
@GroupSequence({ javax.validation.groups.Default.class, SecondPriorityCheck.class })
public interface ValidationSequence {

}

class MyClass {

  @NotNull                       // by default belongs to group Default
  @Size(min = 10, max = 20)      // same here
  @MyCustomVlidatorAnnotation(groups =  SecondPriorityCheck.class) 
  private String field;

}
```

then you have to invoke validator with `ValidationSequence`

```
javax.validation.Validator validator = ..
MyClass instance = ..
validator.validate(instance, ValidationSequence.class)
```

you can find example here https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups